# Thetis example North Sea AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: cluster-computing, petsc

I have tried to fix this error for quiet some time but can't find how to fix it. Is there someone who could help me out? It is an error when running the nort sea 2d model from thetis. [[https://thetisproject.org/demos/demo_2d_north_sea.py.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) ](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_2d_north_sea_test.py", line 35, in <module>
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    m = f.load_mesh("firedrake_default")
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 115, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "PETSc/Log.pyx", line 116, in petsc4py.PETSc.Log.EventDecorator.decorator.wrapped_func
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 945, in load_mesh
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 6 in communicator PYOP2_COMM_WORLD
with errorcode 1.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    coord_element = self._unpickle(self.get_attr(path, PREFIX + "_coordinate_element"))
  File "/scratch/spbolhuis/tools/firedrake/src/firedrake/firedrake/checkpointing.py", line 1359, in _unpickle
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
    return pickle.loads(obj.tobytes())
AttributeError: 'VectorElement' object has no attribute '__dict__'
[cmp050:2760850] 7 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-api.txt / mpi-abort
[cmp050:2760850] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

I have tried to fix this error for quiet some time but can't find how to fix it. Is there someone who could help me out? It is an error when running the nort sea 2d model from thetis. [[https://thetisproject.org/demos/demo_2d_north_sea.py.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) ](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a related Github Issue, you could downgrade ufl maybe ?

By downgrading ufl to the firedrakeproject/ufl@3c95154 using pip inside the Firedrake venv it worked.

See: https://github.com/firedrakeproject/firedrake/issues/2645